# Uniformly link contents of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of systems in a big group that are considered as one. They each have an 'Assessed' status, but I want to somehow link all those systems in the group together, so that if I change the assessment status in any of them, it will update to all those in the group. Is there a way of doing this, apart from assigning one as the 'master' system and having all the others link to that?

Comment: I think you're going to have to give us a hint here. What are you talking about? What sort of "link"? What technology? Macintosh or PC or iPhone?

Comment: It's in Excel. I want the cells to all display the same value, but be able to change a value in any of thise cells and have all the others reflect that. It can be done with a 'parent' cell, but I'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you right, what you want is for

```
  A      B  
------  ------
sys1    Assessed
sys2    Assessed
sys3    Assessed
```

to become

```
  A      B  
------  ------
sys1    foo
sys2    foo
sys3    foo
```

if you type "foo" over any of the "Assessed" cells. The easiest way to do this without using another cell would be to use the worksheet_change() event. Read all about it [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm).

Here's a little something to get you going. Open the VBA editor (ALT+F11) and double-click on your worksheet name. In the resulting code pane put your worksheet_change() code. Maybe something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub

    Dim startCell As Range
    Set startCell = Range("B1")

    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range(startCell, startCell.End(xlDown).Address)

    If Not Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then
        r = Target
    End If

End Sub
```

This will look for changes from B1 to the last contiguous cell below it.